# CSS: Last of type and only if even

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there is possibility to make CSS selector which selects last of type and concurrently only if it is an even element?

Something like:

```
.element:last-of-type:nth-of-type(even) {...}
```

Comment: What you have should work, assuming all the elements with the same element type have that same class.

Comment: Have you tried it for yourself somewhere? Or are you just asking?

Comment: Incase your issue was solved, please mark an answer as correct to close your question, or post an answer by yourself if you found a different solution. If your issue was not solved, please provide us with more info on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option...

```css
li:last-of-type:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as following:

```
element:nth-of-type(even):last-of-type
```

So for example:

```
li:nth-of-type(even):last-of-type{
    color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ovkesfz5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

```
div { height: 10px; background: red; margin-bottom: 10px }
div:not(:nth-child(odd)):last-of-type { background: black }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skco35q3/ I think this is the effect you were after. The last-of-type will be black if there is an odd number. If you uncomment the last div there will be no black item.